# Is this math theorem worth publishing?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, triangles

So I made (and proved) the following statement:

> If $x$ and $nx$ are sides of a right triangle, then the length of the hypotenuse is $x\sqrt{n^2+1}$

Do you recommend this theorem to be published? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem and need not be published.  Note that $n$  need not be an integer here.

Comment: @lulu I made $n$ an integer because if it's a fraction, I have to multiply the expression ($x\sqrt{n^2 + 1}$) by the denominator of $n$ to make it true.

Comment: So this site is "dirt"?

Comment: @WhatsUp no, not at all! I meant should I just ignore it, as if it never happened.

Comment: No...for any $n>0$, which need not even be rational, the hypotenuse is $\sqrt {x^2+n^2x^2}=\sqrt {x^2(1+n^2)}=x\sqrt {1+n^2}$.

Comment: Unrelated: surely $n$ can't be negative?

Comment: @KamalSaleh - if you are doing a fraction, I think you over-worked the problem.  $A^2 + B^2 = C^2$ (pythagorean theorem).  $C^2 = (x^2) + (nx)^2 = x^2 + n^2\,x^2 = x^2(1 + n^2)$.  Square rooting both sides yields $C = x\,\sqrt{1 + n^2}$.

Comment: If these kind of statements were worth publication the whole world would be covered in a 100 meter thick layer of math journals. Heck! I could write 200 math papers per day!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is great! But also, it is probably not something many will want to publish, since the idea behind it is not new: just apply the Pythagorean theorem.

However, "new to the world" and "new to you" are very different things. If coming up with such theorems helps you practice algebra and research, then great! Discovering new-to-you theorems and ideas and results, even if old hat to the world, practices the same skills researchers use. You are probably at the beginnings of your mathematical education, so it would be very hard to find something new-to-the-world, simply because you are only interacting with ideas that are very very old. But keep proving theorems that are new to you! That way when you learn the modern stuff, you will have experience making conjectures and proving theorems that you don't yet know are true.

Comment: +1. The late, great Steve Fisk put it this way: *That someone discovered a result before you is merely an accident of Time; it does not diminish your personal accomplishment.*

Comment: @Blue. too bad being born some 25 centuries after Pythagoras, isn't it?

Comment: @AndreaMori: Indeed ... It's even more frustrating being on this side of the timeline relative to Gauss and Euler.

Comment: @Blue There's always more unknown math than known. But it gets harder and harder to learn your way to the edge of the unknown.

Comment: I need to speak like this to my students as I'm too blunt. I would usually say, "I appreciate your enthusiasm but no, that's not new," and then explain that stuff like this was discovered by the ancient Greeks... But that's probably quite off-putting, whereas your paragraph was all warm and fuzzy. That said, Gregory House was blunt but he was brilliant at his job, so maybe I'm being too self-critical here? Actually, House would had made fun of the student, so at least I'm not doing that...